# Convert this line of Java code to C# code

Tags: c#, java, hex

I need this line of Java code:

```
Integer.toString(256 + (0xFF & arrayOfByte[i]), 16).substring(1)
```

converted to C# since I'm not sure how to work with "0xFF".

**EDIT**
This is the full code:

```
MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
      localMessageDigest.update(String.format(Locale.US, "%s:%s", new Object[] { paramString1, paramString2 }).getBytes());
      byte[] arrayOfByte = localMessageDigest.digest();
      StringBuffer localStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      for (int i = 0; ; i++)
      {
        if (i >= arrayOfByte.length)
          return localStringBuffer.toString();
        localStringBuffer.append(Integer.toString(256 + (0xFF & arrayOfByte[i]), 16).substring(1));
      }
```

Comment: It should just be `0xFF` as AFAIK it's too small and doesn't have MSB set so shouldn't encounter any need for `unchecked`.

Comment: Are you at least able to follow the code.  You'd see that 0xFF is a mask for whatever is in arrayOfByte[i].  Unless what's in the array is larger than a byte I don't see the reason to use it.

Comment: I updated it...maybe it will make more sense in the context of the whole code snippet

Comment: I'm betting the 0xFF is doing some implicit casting since 0xFF is probably treated as an int.  I'm almost certain you could change that 0xFF to -1 and get the same result.

Comment: @asafreedman - In the big picture, you are correct.  But `(0xFF & arrayOfByte[i])` and `(-1 & arrayOfByte[i])` are not the same.

Comment: The result of the operation in this example is the same with 0xFF as it is with -1.  The representation of -1 would be all ones where only the first byte of 0xFF is ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On that note, the actual way you can do this in C# is as follows.

```
String.Format("{0:x2}", arrayOfByte[i]);
```

Which is very similar to the Java

```
String.format("%02x", arrayOfByte[i]);
```

Which is a simpler way to do what they are doing above.

Answer (score 1):

That Java expression is converting a signed byte to unsigned and then to hexadecimal with zero fill.

You should be able to code that in C#.

---

FWIW, the Java code gives the same answer as this:

```
  Integer.toString(256 + arrayOfByte[i], 16).substring(1)
```

or

```
  String.format("%02x", arrayOfByte[i])
```

---

Here's how the original works.  The subexpression

```
  (0xFF & arrayOfByte[i])
```

is equivalent to

```
  (0xFF & ((int) arrayOfByte[i]))
```

which converts a signed byte (-128 to +127) to an unsigned byte (0 to +255).  The purpose of the magic `256 +` in the original is to ensure that the result of `toString` will be 3 hex digits long.  Finally, the leading digit is removed, leaving you with a zero padded 2 digit hex number.

Comment: Also gives the same answer as this. String.format("%02x",arrayOfByte[i])