# Java Format string to C#

Tags: java, c#

Don't understand Java's syntax. How to convert: `"%6d %7.1f %5.1f"` to C# equivalent ?

I keep getting this print out in C#: `%6d %7.1f %5.1f`

**Tried:**

```
"{0:d6} {7:1f} {5:1f}"
```

But, ran into an exception.

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at experiment.Main(String[] args)
```

**The Java code:**

```
String.format("%6d %7.1f %5.1f", int, double, double/double);
```

It's obvious what values will be generated based on variable data types.

EDIT: I just looked at, [Convert this line of Java code to C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635617/convert-this-line-of-java-code-to-c-sharp-code)

**C#**

```
String.Format("{0:x2}", arrayOfByte[i]);
```

**Java**

```
String.format("%02x", arrayOfByte[i]);
```

PLEASE. PLEASE. PLEASE. DO not close this. Kindly. Please.

Comment: Also, your format string is a bit off.  The first number after '{' is a placeholder, starting with 0.  After the ':' you place the formatting.

Comment: The error is telling you the format string is wrong.   You have three '{}', so it should be '"{0:fromatstring} {1:formatstring} {2:format string}'.   In your posted string, the second placeholder starts with 7, when you only have 3 total placeholders.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings for more info.

Comment: For example, (not that familiar with Java), the first placeholder could be something like {0:d}, and with String.Format would be String.Format("{0:d}", 6);

Comment: `PLEASE. PLEASE. PLEASE. DO not close this.` Perhaps show a Java [mcve] with actual inputs and actual output so we can see what you are trying to achieve in C#?

Comment: Do you understand the Java formatting instructions?  After a little googling, the `%6d` will format an integer up to 6 digits, with padding if it is less than 6.  `%7.1f` will print a floating number up to 7 characters (including the decimal point) with a precision of 1, and `%5.1f` will be a floating number up to 5 characters (including the decimal point) with a precision of 1.   Padding is added as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from C# 6. you can use [interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).
For your case you may wanted to try the following:

```
string formattedString = $"{0:d6} {7.1:f} {5.1:f}";
```

before C# 6 you can try the following:

```
string formattedString = String.Format("{0:d6} {1:f} {2:f}", 0, 7.1, 5.1);
```

Comment: Welcome! and happy to help :)

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account the padding and precision in the Java formatting.  May or may not be of importance to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE:  Completely rewrote my original answer based on a (hopefully) better understanding of the Java format specifiers.

Based on my (Google-limited understanding), `%6d`, `%7.1f` and `%5.1f` correspond to the following:

- An integer with up to 6 characters, padded if less than 6.
- A float with up to 7 characters (including the decimal point and decimal portion) with a precision of 1.
- A float with up to 5 characters (including the decimal point and decimal portion) with a precision of 1.

You can accomplish this with C#'s String.Format, like this:

```
var newString = String.Format("{0,6:d} {1,7:f1}, {2,5:f1}", 605, 20.5, 8.22);
```

This will result in the following string:

```
"   605    20.5  8.22"
```

The first digit in each placeholder group (defined by `{` and `}`) corresponds to the argument passed in after the string:

- 0 = 605
- 1 = 20.5
- 2 = 8.22

The second digit, after the `,` refers to the length of the string (including decimal points and decimal portions).

- 6 = 6 characters for the integer
- 7 = 7 characters for the float
- 5 = 5 characters for the float

The letters and numbers after the `:` are the format specifiers.

- d = integer
- f1 = floating with a precision of 1.

Which produces the string above, as follows:

- {0,6:d} turns 605 into "   605" (3 leading spaces due to the 6 before the :)
- {1,7:f1} turns 20.5 into "   20.5" (3 leading spaces due to the 7 before the :)
- {2,5:f1} turns 8.22 into " 8.2" (1 leading space due to the 5 before the : and 1 decimal number due to the precision).

As I said earlier, check [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) and [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for more information.

Comment: Hi Tim, %6d %7.1f %5.1f <-- how ? Because the way I understand it, is that those are replaced by other values in Java. Although I do not know what they actually mean.

Comment: I don't know much about Java, but I believe that's just Java's way of formatting strings.  It'll take the 6 and format as a decimal, the 7.1 as a float, etc.   The above code snippet will return "6 7.10 5.10" (because I didn't indicate the precision.  What does the output in Java look like?

Comment: @Tim `It's obvious what values will be generated based on variable data types.` is what the OP said the last time we asked to see the output.

Comment: @mjwills I'm not familiar enough with Java's string formatting to say for certain (its also past my bedtime so maybe my brain shut off).   The `double/double` thing confuses me, though I've been able to figure out `%6d` works with the length of the integer passed in.  That's why I edited my answer to see it's a very basic intro to String.Format in C#.